# Git: copy local branch into another local directory

Tags: git

Sorry for asking this dumb question.

I am trying to copy my repo (local) into another local directory. If I simply do `CMD + c` and `CMD + v` of my repo, I actually copy all the branches of my local repo. How do I only copy one branch?

Thanks

Comment: What do you want to copy really? It doesn't make sense to try to copy a branch from one to another repository.

Comment: I got a repo store in `desktop`. I wanna make a copy of it into another directory, say `my_documents` @NiVeR

Comment: If you are already copying the repository to a new directory, just checkout to the branch in question in that new directory.

Of course, what you're *trying* to do is not something that git is meant to be used for, so be warned that it's not the best solution.

Comment: so you want to clone the whole repo?

Comment: Only a single branch of the whole repo

Answer (score 26):

I had the same problem when we were moving our repo to a new server.

I just did from my old repo:

`git push <path_to_new_local_repo> <branch_name>`

and it worked perfect.

Comment: This answer is underrated.

Comment: Wow it does work perfect

Comment: Handy one, thank you :) Also only `git push <path_to_new_local_repo>` will push the branch you are currently in.

Comment: can you do the inverse  `git pull <path_to_old_local_repo>` from the new repo?

Comment: If you get error `error: By default, updating the current branch in a non-bare repository
remote: is denied` then make sure you initiate the new local repo as a bare repo `git init --bare`

Answer (score 7):

Every git repository contains the whole git commit tree, so you cannot get a git repository only with a single branch by copy and paste git folder.

But`git worktree` is designed for this situation.

---

Just type this command in your original git repository.

```
git worktree add -b <your-new-branch-name> <your-new-directory> <your-base-branch>
```

This command means that you'll create a new folder in the path `your-new-directory`, and then create a new branch named `your-new-branch-name` based on the `your-base-branch` branch.

For example, you can type this below to create a folder named `MyAnotherFolder` beside your original one, and create a new branch `temp/my-copy` based on `master`.

```
git worktree add -b temp/my-copy ../MyAnotherFolder master
```

---

If you delete the folder in the future, type this command to remove the worktree reference.

```
git worktree prune
```

Comment: if you don't want to the branch in the original directory to diverge from the one in the new directory `-b new-branch` can be ommitted if i'm not mistaken; one side effect is you'll have to cd the the new directory to checkout that branch

Answer (score 1):

It seems like what you're saying you want is a new repo in the second directory, that contains only a single branch.  It can be done, though it's a bit unusual and I wonder if it's really the best way to do whatever you're trying to do...

Well, anyway, in most cases if you want to copy a repo it's better to use `git clone` than to use external tools to copy the files.  In this case, you could say

```
git clone --single-branch --branch <branch_name> file://localhost/path/to/existing/repo
```

This initializes a new repo and fetches just the history and objects required for the branch named `<branch_name>`.  The new repo will refer to the existing local repo as a remote named `origin`.  You can undo this if you want by `cd`ing into the new repo and saying

```
git remote remove origin
```

If your local repo has a remote, and you want the new repo to also use *that* remote as its `origin`, then it's probably easier to clone from the remote instead of from the local copy.